# Heroku Python socket connection fails

Tags: python, sockets, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a python socket server to Heroku, but it seems that the socket connection is not well made... In my case, the `accept()` method should wait for a socket connection to be made, but it seems that it fires even if I don't run my `client.py` script...

Also, when running the client, the connection is indeed made, but the server doesn't receive nor send any data...

What am I doing wrong? All of this works locally... (changing the port from 80 to 12345 and the address to localhost)...

Here's what I have so far :

```py
# server.py
import socket
import os

server = socket.socket()
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 12345))
server.bind(("0.0.0.0", port))
server.listen(5)

# should wait for an actual connection, but fires right away
s, _ = server.accept()

# should wait to receive "Hello, world! (from client)", but receives b''
s.recv(1024)

s.send("Hello, world! (from server)".encode())

s.close()
```

```py
# client.py
import socket

s = socket.socket()

print("connecting to server...")
# "...my-heroku-app.." changed to the actual heroku app url
s.connect(("my-heroku-app.herokuapp.com", 80))

print("sending data...")
s.send("Hello, world! (from client)".encode())

print("receiving data...")

# should receive "Hello, world! (from server)",
# but blocks because the server already stopped
print(s.recv(1024).decode())

s.close()
```

```
# Procfile
web: python server.py
```

I've also tried to put the `s.recv()` in a loop until data received is not None, but that just loops forever... (on the server side)

What am I doing wrong here? Is the server binding (address and port) correct? Does Heroku support that kind of server? I don't seem to find any info about how to do it (there only are examples using Flask and other web-servers frameworks...).

### EDIT

After some logging, it seems that `172.18.17.53` is the IP that always connects to the server and keeps it busy. It also seems that this IP is unreachable because the send() function blocks...

I've tried to add `s.settimeout(0.05)` but it changed nothing for the `send()` method...