# python socket server in Heroku

Tags: python, sockets, heroku

Im trying to deploy a server using the socket module to heroku. The server runs correctly when I look at the logs from heroku, the problem is that i have not been able to connect to it with the client and it seems that an ip address is constantly connecting to the server.

Procfile: `web: python Server.py`

The server I built has this structure.

```py
import socket
import os
from _thread import start_new_thread

PORT = int(os.environ(['PORT']))
HOST =  '0.0.0.0'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    pass

s.listen(2)

def threaded_client(conn):
    print(f'CONNECTED -> {conn}')
    while True:
        # some logic
        pass



if __name__== '__main__':
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
```

And the client.

```py
import socket


PORT = 80
HOST = 'https://my-heroku-app.herokuapp.com'

client =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect((HOST,PORT))
```

I have a similar issue as the one mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164238/heroku-python-socket-connection-fails)

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You hardcoded your port to `80`. On Heroku you need to bind the port to the env variable `$PORT` https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error

Comment: @TinNguyen I used the env variable on the server, I used port 80 on the client.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use heroku to host a tcp server ,you need a service like linode https://www.linode.com/ ,or aws ,but you can use heroku to host a websocket server which you can use a python websocket client to connect to ,like so

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("ws://myapp.herokuapp.com")
print("Sending 'Hello, World'...")
ws.send("Hello, World")
print("Sent")
print("Receiving...")
result = ws.recv()
print("Received '%s'" % result)
ws.close()
```